# Creating a virtual circuit?

Tags: c#, udp, .net-3.5, internet-connection, rudp

I need to send both reliable and unreliable packets over the Internet. I can't use TCP and UDP because this is going to cause the TCP starvation/UDP dominance effect. For more information about this effect have a look at the "Mixing TCP and UDP" section in [this link](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/solutions/Enterprise/WAN_and_MAN/QoS_SRND/QoS-SRND-Book/VPNQoS.html). Thus, I need to implement reliable UDP. I want to make UDP connection-oriented. I need to create virtual circuits in order to make UDP connection-oriented. Is this possible? Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Isn't connection-oriented UDP basically TCP? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: No it isn't TCP. What I want to get is a connection oriented protocol with unreliable unordered packets. TCP is a connection oriented protocol with reliable ordered packets. There is a huge difference.

Comment: Ah I see. Sounds like you'll have to roll your own then. I personally haven't heard of anything like that.